# why I don't need to import the supporting modules?

Tags: python

The `get_square_root()` function relies on the `math` module. To call the `get_square_root()` function in `analysis.py`, I don't need to import the `math` module, why is that?

```py
# calculator.py

import math

def get_square_root(a):
    return math.sqrt(a)
```

```py
#analysis.py

import calculator

calculator.get_square_root(5)
```

Something I know about `import` in python (Correct me if I understood sth. wrong). When `import calculator`, the Python interpreter reads the whole `calculator.py` module, but the objects in the module not to be accessed by `<ModuleName>.<ObjectName>`. This is how I call the `get_square_root()` in `analysis.py`. But how the `get_square_root()` access `math` since there no `math` in `analysis.py` ?

Comment: `math` gets imported when you import `calculator`.

Comment: "why I don't need to import the math module" - because you're not using it.

Comment: Because it is imported and available in `calculatory.py`...

Comment: @zvone thanks.. but the code still works when I only import the function as `from calculator import get_square_root` and call `get_square_root(5)`

Comment: `from` imports still load the whole module.

Comment: This is related to scoping. See [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4518341) Python also something special with modules to make star imports work, though I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

When you run `calculator` in any way, `math` is bound in its module scope, making it accessible to `get_square_root`.

When you run `import calculator` in `analysis`, `math` is still in the module scope for `get_square_root`, plus `calculator` is bound in the scope of `analysis` so you can access it as `calculator.math`.

When you run `from calculator import get_square_root` in `analysis`, `math` is still in the module scope for `get_square_root`, but you cannot access it from `analysis` since `calculator` is not bound.

Comment: P.s. let me know if any of my terminology is wrong. I'm still a bit shaky on scoping.